# how to get the type of the file before its compression

Tags: c, file, compression, file-extension

For example, if we have the following file: `file.txt` that after the compression is now `file.new` (***new*** is the new extension) , how to obtain that `.txt` extension, that is forgotten?

I need that to decompress the file.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Just uncompress it?

Comment: You cannot. You cannot assume the type of a file just by its name or its contents, compressed or not. You can only [*guess* it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). In some cases, that guessing is reliable, in some other cases it isn't. Text files do not have a magic number for example (and by text I mean ANY kind of text file). So either you store the original name along with the compressed data, or you cannot get that information back.

Comment: Text files do, however, have distinguishing characteristics, as any Bayesian filter can attest.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you lose the file name extension you can't get it back. It's as simple as this.

However, there might be chances depending on the compression format. Some formats *do* store the original file name (along with other informations) in the compressed file. And the "decompressor" will be able to recreate those properties.

Anyway, it's good practise to name a compressed file with an *additional* extension, in your case `file.txt.new`.

---

Oh, and you don't need to know the file name extension to uncompress the compressed file. Just uncompress it and give it a temporary name. As @MarcoBonelli said, file contents and file name extensions have no fixed relation. They are just a convention to handle them conveniently.

For example: You can rename a EXE to DOCX. Windows will show the Word icon but it is still an executable. Windows will not attempt to run it, though.

To know *what* a file contains can be difficult. The [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) Marco linked to might give you some hint.